# Conditional drawer with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a conditional navigation in app.js with asyncstorage.

In app.js I have a constructor with AsyncStorage modifying state and in function of state show a different drawer:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getData().then((vist) => {
      if(vist !== null) {
        this.setState({vist: 1});
      } else {
        this.setState({vist: 0});
      }
    });
  }

  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('vist');

      return value;

    } catch(e) {

    }
  }
```

and in render:

```
render(){
    return (
      { this.state.vist == 0 ? 
      <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      :
      <AppContainerFinal
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      }
    );
  }
```

The problem is that I change asynstorage in other page it's impossible refresh app.js to change state in app.js

If I put setstate in render, this doesn't stop rendering any time.

How can I do it?